# Jquery slider load every tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, slider, jquery-tabs

I have problem with jquery tabs and slider.. My problem  is when ı click slider item for example 4's element of slider.. it load every tabs about 4 element.I want to make when I click one element of slider. it can be load only active tab.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qqtr7/4/)

HTML

```
<title>jQuery UI Slider - Slider scrollbar</title>
<body>
    <div class="scroll-pane ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <div class="scroll-content">
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header"></div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">
                <div class="arabadiv" onclick="yukle()" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color: darkviolet "></div>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">
                <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">4</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">5</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">6</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">7</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">8</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">9</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">10</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">11</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">12</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">13</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">14</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">15</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">16</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">17</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">18</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">19</div>
            <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">20</div>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll-bar-wrap ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
            <div class="scroll-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:left"></div>
    <div id="tabs" class="tabs-bottom">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Genel Bakış</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tasarım</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aksesuar</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">Model</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-5">Renk</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-6">Fiyat</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabs-spacer"></div>
        <div style="width:auto; height:800px; background-color:red" id="tabs-1"></div>
        <div style="width:auto; height:900px; background-color:yellowgreen" id="tabs-2"></div>
        <div style="width:auto; height:800px; background-color:darkcyan" id="tabs-3"></div>
        <div style="width:auto; height:800px; background-color:bisque" id="tabs-4"></div>
        <div style="width:auto; height:800px; background-color:firebrick" id="tabs-5"></div>
        <div style="width:auto; height:800px; background-color:ghostwhite" id="tabs-6"></div>
```

JAVA

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    // fix the classes
    $(".tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav, .tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav > *")
        .removeClass("ui-corner-all ui-corner-top")
        .addClass("ui-corner-bottom");

    // move the nav to the bottom
    $(".tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav").appendTo(".tabs-bottom");
});

$(function () {
    //scrollpane parts
    var scrollPane = $(".scroll-pane"),
        scrollContent = $(".scroll-content");

    //build slider
    var scrollbar = $(".scroll-bar").slider({
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            if (scrollContent.width() > scrollPane.width()) {
                scrollContent.css("margin-left", Math.round(
                ui.value / 100 * (scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width())) + "px");
            } else {
                scrollContent.css("margin-left", 0);
            }
        }
    });

    //append icon to handle
    var handleHelper = scrollbar.find(".ui-slider-handle")
        .mousedown(function () {
        scrollbar.width(handleHelper.width());
    })
        .mouseup(function () {
        scrollbar.width("100%");
    })
        .append("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical'></span>")
        .wrap("<div class='ui-handle-helper-parent'></div>").parent();

    //change overflow to hidden now that slider handles the scrolling
    scrollPane.css("overflow", "hidden");

    //size scrollbar and handle proportionally to scroll distance
    function sizeScrollbar() {
        var remainder = scrollContent.width() - scrollPane.width();
        var proportion = remainder / scrollContent.width();
        var handleSize = scrollPane.width() - (proportion * scrollPane.width());
        scrollbar.find(".ui-slider-handle").css({
            width: handleSize,
                "margin-left": -handleSize / 2
        });
        handleHelper.width("").width(scrollbar.width() - handleSize);
    }

    //reset slider value based on scroll content position
    function resetValue() {
        var remainder = scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width();
        var leftVal = scrollContent.css("margin-left") === "auto" ? 0 : parseInt(scrollContent.css("margin-left"));
        var percentage = Math.round(leftVal / remainder * 100);
        scrollbar.slider("value", percentage);
    }

    //if the slider is 100% and window gets larger, reveal content
    function reflowContent() {
        var showing = scrollContent.width() + parseInt(scrollContent.css("margin-left"), 10);
        var gap = scrollPane.width() - showing;
        if (gap > 0) {
            scrollContent.css("margin-left", parseInt(scrollContent.css("margin-left"), 10) + gap);
        }
    }

    //change handle position on window resize
    $(window).resize(function () {
        resetValue();
        sizeScrollbar();
        reflowContent();
    });
    //init scrollbar size
    setTimeout(sizeScrollbar, 10); //safari wants a timeout
});
```

CSS

```
    .scroll-pane {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 99%;
    float:left;
}
.scroll-content {
    width: 2440px;
    float: left;
}
.scroll-content-item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 96px;
    text-align: center;
}
.scroll-bar-wrap {
    clear: left;
    padding: 0 4px 0 2px;
    margin: 0 -1px -1px -1px;
}
.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider {
    background: none;
    border:0;
    height: 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-handle-helper-parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle {
    top:.2em;
    height: 1.5em;
}
.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle .ui-icon {
    margin: -8px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
/* force a height so the tabs don't jump as content height changes */
 #tabs .tabs-spacer {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}
.tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav {
    clear: left;
    padding: 0 .2em .2em .2em;
}
.tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav li {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 .2em 1px 0;
    border-bottom: auto;
    border-top: 0;
}
.tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to see what you mean. If you'd like to load only the elements selected you could make it's class equal to the id of what you want to load and then use that to identify what you would like to load.

HTML

```
<div id="selected_item" class="item_to_load">
```

Java

```
var loadMe = document.getElementsById("selected_item");

function showOrLoad () {
   var $item-to-load = document.getElementsByClassName(loadMe); 
}
```

It might be that you need to give each slider item an id?

If you gave all the slider items a unique ID you could then hide the 'class' and show the 'ID'.

i.e.

HTML

```
<div id="uniqueID" class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">14</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.scroll-content-item').hide();
$('#uniqueID').show();
```

---

UPDATE

I think you're saying you need to add another class to all the slider items. Then when you select a tab item you need to hide the corresponding slider items.

Comment: I mean in page top have scroll slider . when I click  scroll content item. it's load every tabs at once.

Comment: I think I get what you mean. So say you clicked tab 'Tasarim', you might want it to only load slider '4,5,6' say?

Comment: :) my english not so good.. thank you for help .. I mean when ı click  slider "4" . it must load only  active tab. and when ı change tab .then its can  load other tab but slider item must be same .it must be  "4"..

Comment: How can I make each slider content div at once.I mean I have 8 slider item and each item have 8 tabs. and loading big data from local.How can I make when open first time.all content loaded.

Answer (score 0):

By the way you could just use the [`JQuery Cycle Plugin`](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/), works with both `<div>` and `<ul`> elements. Which would solve a lot of your problems without reinventing the wheel. You can read the [beginner demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/begin.html), [intermediate demos](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int.html) or [advanced demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/adv.html), or something like this would like fine.

```
<!-- Pull some Libraries-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<!-- Slider code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slider').cycle('slideX');
</script>
<!-- Slider itself-->
<ul id="slider">
    <li><img src='img1.png' title='first image' /></li>
    <li><img src='img2.png' title='second image' /></li>
    <li><img src='img3.png' title='third image' /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ı dont understand how to use it